# Refine wrapfigure[]{r} or wrapfigure[]{l}

Tags: wrapfigure

I have often used this form of the wrapfigure, but I notice that sometimes I have this problem.

```
 \documentclass[pdftex,10pt,a4paper]{book}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0 mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0 mm}
%\setlength{\headheight}{7 mm} %latezza capotesta
%\setlength{\headsep}{9 mm} 
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0 mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0 mm} %% per le note a bordo?
\setlength{\textheight}{230mm} %Altezza Testo
\setlength{\textwidth}{150mm}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-1]
    \begin{wrapfigure}[11]{l}[\dimexpr \marginparwidth]{5.5cm}
        \centering\raisebox{\dimexpr \topskip-\height}{%
            \includegraphics[width=5.0cm]{example-image-a}}
        \captionof{figure}{Titolo dell'immagine casuale}
    \end{wrapfigure}\hfil

\lipsum[2-3]

\begin{wrapfigure}[11]{r}[\dimexpr \marginparwidth]{5.5cm}
    \centering\raisebox{\dimexpr \topskip-\height}{%
        \includegraphics[width=5.0cm]{example-image-a}}
    \captionof{figure}{Titolo dell'immagine casuale}
\end{wrapfigure}\hfil


\lipsum[4-5]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[textheight=230mm,
            textwidth=150mm,
            marginparwidth=0mm]{geometry} % for defining page layout
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt} % <--- push image to top of paragraph
\usepackage{caption}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{blindtext}    % wrapfigure doesn't work well with lipsum

\begin{document}

    \begin{wrapfigure}[12]{l}{0.4\linewidth}% explicit reserved space for wrapfigure
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Titolo dell'immagine casuale}
    \end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5.5cm}% implicit reserved space for wrapfigure
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5.0cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Titolo dell'immagine casuale}
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your main concern is over-printing at the bottom, yet you manually specified the number of lines to wrap. So either omit the `[11]` argument entirely, or change it to `[12]`.

There are other issues that you did not circle in red.

You have an empty one-line paragraph near the start of each wrapfig, which appears as a blank line in the output. If that is not on purpose, get rid of the `\hfil` which causes it.

The `\raisebox` is not doing what it seems you want (something about positioning at the top of a page). I'm guessing that you want to reduce the vertical gap around the wrapfig. So instead use `\setlength{\intextsep}{4pt}` or some other length.

Using `\captionof` is unnecessary, but doesn't hurt. (I suspected it would break the automatic-width feature for `0pt` width, but it seems to work.)

I don't know why you specify a margin overhang, with the margin width set to zero. Just leave out that optional argument.

In summary, I think you are trying too hard.  You could use

```
\lipsum[1-1]

\setlength\intextsep{4pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{5.5cm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5.0cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Titolo dell'immagine casuale}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[2-3]
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work better:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,a4paper]{book}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0 mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0 mm}
%\setlength{\headheight}{7 mm} %latezza capotesta
%\setlength{\headsep}{9 mm} 
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0 mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0 mm} %% per le note a bordo?
\setlength{\textheight}{230mm} %Altezza Testo
\setlength{\textwidth}{150mm}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-1]
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}[\dimexpr \marginparwidth]{5.5cm}
        \centering\raisebox{\dimexpr \topskip-\height}{%
            \includegraphics[width=5.0cm]{example-image-a}}
        \caption{Titolo dell'immagine casuale}
    \end{wrapfigure}\hfil

\lipsum[2-3]

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}[\dimexpr \marginparwidth]{5.5cm}
    \centering\raisebox{\dimexpr \topskip-\height}{%
        \includegraphics[width=5.0cm]{example-image-a}}
    \caption{Titolo dell'immagine casuale}
\end{wrapfigure}\hfil


\lipsum[4-5]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Avoid `\captionof{}{}` and just use `\caption{}` (wrapfigure environment handles caption itself but possibly doesn't recognize `\captionof`) ... Also by giving the optional argument of `11` lines ... you "force" that behavior ...