# Aligning \begin{wrapfigure} \caption relative to the image?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

I just installed latex today to learn how to use it. Currently testing it out on a report. My question is how to best go about centering a \caption relative to the image. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt, onecolumn]{amsart}
    \usepackage{geometry}   
    \geometry{letterpaper} 
    \geometry{landscape} 
    \usepackage[parfill]{parskip} 
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{epstopdf}
    \DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}
    {`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}
    
    \title{Område-och-landskapsanalys av Väst på stan}
    \author{test}
    \date{2021/30/01}

   
    \begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    \pagebreak
    \tableofcontents
    
        \section{Introduktion}
        
        \section{Metod}
        \section{Analys av området utifrån ett vinterperspektiv}
  
 
        \begin{figure}[h]
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{karta.png}
        \caption{Grov uppskatting på den valda rutten under fältbesöket}        
        \end{figure}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{10cm}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{korsning.jpg}
\caption{vägkorsning i Umeå VÄGSAKNAS }
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please add a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805) to your question.

Comment: For start see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551794/.

Comment: Welcome. Your picture shows the caption not obeying the current width, but does not show whatever caused that change to the behavior of `\caption` (some package or document class).

Comment: I've added the code