# \blindtext vs \lipsum

Tags: lipsum, blindtext

Both `\blindtext` and `\lipsum` quickly provide dummy text. Most users seem to prefer `\lipsum`. But besides from the fact that `\blindtext` offers more features is there any aplication where one is against the other the better choice?

EDIT: In this answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/551807/224762) @Zarko mentions that `\wrapfigure` does not work well with `\lipsum`. So I thought here is more into that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding the `\wrapfigure`--`\lipsum` thing: it's a [known bug](https://github.com/PhelypeOleinik/lipsum/issues/1) and it will be fixed in the next release (hopefully next week or so).

Comment: The `\wrapfigure` issue has been fixed and the new version is already available.  Feedback is welcome!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<sub>I am the current maintainer of `lipsum`, so my answer may be biased in the sense that I know what `lipsum` can do, and I don't know `blindtext` as much.  That said...</sub>

They are quite different packages, so you can't really say “this one is better”.  They have a very different set of features, so your choice will largely depend on what you want to do.  In general:

- `lipsum` is a lot more focused on just returning you the raw dummy text, but giving you control of how much and how the text is output, allowing for some programming usages.
- `blindtext` gives you very little flexibility on what text is output (it has very few different paragraphs built in), but it can give you a more document-like structure including, for example, maths, lists, and sectioning.

Here are the main features of each:

#### `lipsum`

- Provides you with 150 different paragraphs of the “Lorem Ipsum” text, plus other dummy texts that can be selected using `\SetLipsumText`;
- Allows you to define your own dummy text, that you can load with `\SetLipsumText`;
- You can select between the available paragraphs using `\lipsum[<par-range>]` as well as sentences in those paragraphs using `\lipsum[<par-range>][<sentence-range>]`;
- You can add “delimiters” (any piece of TeX code) around paragraphs and sentences, giving you greater control of the output;
- With the `\unpacklipsum` command you can extract chunks of dummy text that can be used in programming-like tasks (parsing a string, for example, for counting words) that cannot be done with `\lipsum` (or with `\blindtext` for that matter).

###### `lipsum` v2.4

(released July 22nd, 2021)

- `\lipsum` will automatically change the hyphenation patterns to match the language of the dummy text (Latin for the default “Lorem Ipsum” text), so you will get better line breaks;
- The language switching integrates with `babel`, so language-specific features will be enabled if `babel` is loaded;
- It will also allow you to switch between hyphenation patterns so you can compare them if you want;
- A new dummy text in (pseudo-)Czech will be shipped with the package.

#### `blindtext`

- You can choose to produce a single paragraph or a full document (as demonstrated in Werner's answer) producing a visually-real document;
- It allows you to separately typeset (`itemize`, `enumerate`, or `description`) lists, possibly nested, to demonstrate the layout of lists, in case you are designing a document class, for example;
- It allows you to randomise the output using the `random` option (you could hack that for `\lipsum`, if needed);
- It provides pangrams (the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog) in case you want to see the appearance of fonts, for example;
- It provides a wider set of predefined languages: English (UK and US), German (old and new ortography), Catalan, Latin, and French;
- Allows you to add text at the beginning and end of a paragraph as `lipsum` does (but not around sentences);
- Integrates with `babel` and `polyglossia` to switch languages automatically when languages are switched in the document (contrary to `\lipsum` which switches the language to match the dummy text).

Answer (score 6):

If you just want dummy text, either works. If you want a quick *document*, then [`blindtext`](//ctan.org/pkg/blindtext) is better as it provides `\blinddocument` (and `\Blinddocument`) to quickly create a bigger document with sectional units and lists.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[toc]{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

The comparable code using only [`lipsum`](//ctan.org/lipsum) basics would be much longer (read "less quick to prepare").

Comment: I made an edit to my question: In this answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/551807/224762) @Zarko mentions that `\wrapfigure` does not work well with `\lipsum`. So I thought here is more into that.

Comment: @Roland: That might be because [`lipsum`](//ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) also updates `\par`. You can use `\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}`.

Comment: @Werner No, it's unrelated to `\par`.  The bug is because `\lipsum` introduces a `\begingroup`...`\endgroup` that confuses `\wrapfigure`.  Will be fixed in the next release