# How do I edit where the page number goes

Tags: page-numbering

Right now, the page number goes after the title page. How do I make the first page go lower down? It says page 4. I want to make it 1. (keep in mind this is 3 pages after the title page)
[image]

Comment: Have a look at front- and mainmatter. Can you make a compilable minimal working example which allows us to reproduce the issue?

Comment: how do i make a compilable minimal working example?

Comment: See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe

Comment: Welcome. // If you look for a procedure: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9027/245790 . // Also consider using blindtext to reduce code without sacrificing your problem, e.g. from https://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext . Examples: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/604917/245790

Comment: You can use `\setcounter{page}{1}`,  but if this is book class, `\frontmattter` and `\mainmatter` are a better solution.  You don't want two page ones.